# Register a Tenant in Azure

Tags: .net, azure, active-directory, multi-tenant

I'm developing a multi-tenant application.  I've been developing for years, but i'm new to Azure development.  I'm trying to get pointed in the right direction regarding a specific area.

I have a requirement to Register a Tenant.  For example, a potential customer comes to my website and decides they want to purchase services from us.  I provide a link that takes them to a page on my site that allows them to enter their information and sign up.

I'm trying to understand how that information gets setup on the Azure side using .net.  This would also include getting them setup in Windows Azure Active Directory (WAAD).

Comment: Does your service require anything to do with tenant's Azure Active Directory? For example, do they authenticate against their Azure AD?

Comment: No requirement just yet.  It may be an option in the future though.